# Is there any mean to crypto data of ledger in Composer business network?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I think encryption of data in ledger should be performed by application (client application and chaincode) in Hyperledger Fabric.
Is there any mean to crypto data of ledger using Hyperledger Composer ? Should I implement encryption in client application or transaction processing function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

correct, it should be performed on the client side.  So you would implement any encryption client side as opposed to the Hyperledger Composer TP functions. If you encrypt the data (eg. even at a field/attribute level), then you will need to provide a means to share the decryption keys. As far as the ledger at rest is concerned, it can be encrypted via file system encryption on the peer, and for any data in-transit, can be encrypted via TLS.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I understand data encryption on ledger is application's responsibility, but I have choice to use encrypted file system and TLS for better privacy / data protection.